# Minimal requirements for bedtime shema

Tags: halacha, shema, evening-night, hamapil

What is the minimal required text to say for the bedtime shema?  Is it sufficient to say only Hamapil and the first paragraph of shema?

Answer (score 3):

You asked if hamapil and Shema is good enough,  see in SA OC 239, 1,  this is exactly what he says:

> קורא על מטתו פרשה ראשונה של שמע ומברך המפיל חבלי שינה על עיני וכו'.ואומר יושב בסתר עליון. ואומר ה' מה רבו צרי עד לה' הישועה ואומר ברוך ה' ביום ברוך ה' בלילה ברוך ה' בשכבנו ברוך ה' בקומנו ויאמר ה' אל השטן יגער ה' בך השטן וגו' ה' שומרך וגו' מעתה ועד עולם בידך אפקיד רוחי וגו' יברכך ה' וגו' עד וישם לך שלום ואומר השכיבנו עד סמוך לחתימה:‏
>
> He reads at the bedside the first paragraph of Shema and Hamapil chevle shena... Yoshev beseter...,

According to Gemara Bavli and Yerushalmi he needs to say some mizmorim and prayers for protection. The list enumerated by the SA is based on examples from Chachamim but is not an obligation.  For the order if Shema is before or after the birkat hamapil,  there is a Machloket. The order you cited in the question is the order followed by the Rambam. Most people follow it.

#### Shema and Hamapil are presented as a duty (Berachot 60b):

> הנכנס לישן על מטתו אומר משמע ישראל עד והיה אם שמוע ואומר ברוך המפיל חבלי שינה על עיני ותנומה על עפעפי ומאיר לאישון בת עין יהי רצון מלפניך ה' אלהי שתשכיבני לשלום ותן חלקי בתורתך ותרגילני לידי מצוה ואל תרגילני לידי עבירה ואל תביאני לידי חטא ולא לידי עון ולא לידי נסיון ולא לידי בזיון וישלוט בי יצר טוב ואל ישלוט בי יצר הרע ותצילני מפגע רע ומחלאים רעים ואל יבהלוני חלומות רעים והרהורים רעים ותהא מטתי שלמה לפניך והאר עיני פן אישן המות ברוך אתה ה' המאיר לעולם כולו בכבודו
>
> On going to bed one says from **'Hear, oh Israel'** to 'And it shall come to pass if ye hearken diligently'. Then he says:  **'Blessed is He who causes the bands of sleep to fall upon my eyes and slumber on my eyelids, and gives light to the apple of the eye. May it be Thy will, O Lord, my God, to make me lie down in peace, and set my portion in Thy law and accustom me to the performance of religious duties, but do not accustom me to transgression; and bring me not into sin, or into iniquity, or into temptation, or into contempt. And may the good inclination have sway over me and let not the evil inclination have sway over me. And deliver me from evil hap and sore diseases, and let not evil dreams and evil thoughts disturb me, and may my couch be flawless before Thee, and enlighten mine eyes lest I sleep the sleep of death. Blessed art Thou, oh Lord, who givest light to the whole world in Thy glory.'**

Comment: What is hamapil?

Comment: @Aaron The blessing said before going to sleep. It opens ברוך אתה ה אלקנו מלך העולם **המפיל** חבלי שינה על עיני... It's parallel to the blessing in the morning upon waking up המעביר שינה מעיני...

Answer (score 2):

Technically all one needs to say is shema/veahavta and hamapil (That's what one says on the first night of pesach).

The rest of krias shema is for protection against mazikin.

Comment: Source? The Rambam 7:2 doesn't agree with this

Answer (score 1):

Deoraita, the obligation is to say "Shma Yisroel.." through the first paragraph (until "Vehayah im shamoa"). It can be said in any language, and "Shma" through "echad" requires extra kavanah. 
(somewhere within the first 15 pages of Missechet Bruchot)

I'm not sure if Hamapil is required Derabanan, or just a strong suggestion.

more info:
http://www.torah.org/learning/halacha/classes/class264.html#

pdf download: http://yctchevre.blogspot.com/2008/04/milin-havivin-volume-3-online.html
(from : http://drewkaplans.blogspot.com/2008/04/birkat-hamapil-article-published.html)

Comment: Do you mean there's a requirement _mid'oraysa_ to say part of "_Sh'ma_" even if one already did so as part of _maariv_?

Comment: Sh'ma is only d'orayta if you didn't yet say it after the correct time. Ideally, one shouldn't delay the mitzvah until going to sleep. According to many opinions, the second parsha is also part of the mitzvah (and the third would fulfill the mitzvah to remember yetzias mitzrayim).